# How do you get a certain portion of the Document root with PHP?

Tags: php

I am working a website for my friends and myself, and it needs to be a bit secure.
I have an SQL database for storing user info,
I store the variables for the database outside the public files and have
a function to retrieve them.

With this function which is called `getSQL_Info($n)` it takes the
line in the text file and breaks it up and puts the
variables into an array and returns `array[$n]`.

In order to load the file with the variables I must provide the location, instead of having the path written in the function, I would like to have it so you do something like
`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and use that to get the base part of the path.

Essentially, I would like to have the path `"home2/(mySecretUsername)/config/file.txt"`
when it gives me `"home2/(mySecretUsername)/public_html/fpi"`.

I kinda just need a good explanation of how to take the `"home2/(mySecretUsername)/"` part out and add `"config/file.txt"`.

Thanks for your time,
if I explained my question poorly please do tell me and I will add further information.
-Michael Mitchell

Comment: Why not manually reference the path?

Comment: The path contains my username to the host server, I cannot change that, so I would rather it be more of a secret :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this approach work for you?

```
function getConfigFile() {
   $components = explode('/' , $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
   $componentLen = count($components);
   if ($componentLen < 3) {
       return ''; // Something goes wrong
   }
   $components2 = array_slice($path, 0, $componentLen - 2);
   return implode( '/' , $components2) . '/config/file.txt'
}
```

It's obviously platform-dependent but looks like it does the job.